# Как запустить свой сервер на node.js глобально?

Tags: node.js, веб-сервер, site

Здравствуйте. Недавно начал делать один-проект сайт и сервер тестировал только локально сам с собой, но там есть такие функции как взаимодействие между пользователями и это я в одиночку протестировать не могу. Попробовал найти информацию в интернете но не разобрался, везде пишут что-то вроде что нужен хостинг который вроде как запустит свой сервер, но зачем мне их сервер если я сделал свой на node.js? Ну и вот я хочу спросить как возможно запустить глобально сайт? пока это не релиз, просто хотел бы протестировать работоспособность. Или просто может есть какая-то другая возможность чтобы протестировать его с другими пользователями в интернете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала вы можете воспользоватся  своей локальной сетью. С помощью команды ipconfig посмотрите свой ip в локальной сети. По этому ip вы можете заходить на свой сервер со всех устройств, подключенных к вашей домашней сети (телефон, ноут, другой комп, планшет итд)

Если вы всё же хотите выставить сайт в интернет, то оптимальный вариант для тестирования на мой взгляд - [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction). Это бесплатно, относительно легко деплоить, не нужно мучиться с найстрокой сервера.

Вот код на nodejs, который выведет в консоль ваш локальный ip адрес:

```
const ifaces = require('os').networkInterfaces();
const localhost = Object.keys(ifaces).reduce((host,ifname) => {
    let iface = ifaces[ifname].find(iface => !('IPv4' !== iface.family || iface.internal !== false));
    return iface? iface.address : host;
}, '127.0.0.1');
console.log(localhost);
```

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете воспользоваться сервисом [Now](https://zeit.co/now). Он позоволяет очень просто развернуть ваше приложение. И если вы не используете много ресурсов, то это будет бесплатно.

Ставите пакет **now**

```
npm install -g now
```

После в корне вашего проекта запускаете

```
now
```

При первом запуске вас спросят про **email** и вам надо будет его подтвердить. Но последующие запуски это делать не нужно.

В результате вы получите сервер (глобальный) с вашим приложением видимый в сети. Имя сервера будет выбрано случайно, но вам его сообщат. Чтобы другие люди могли использовать ваш сервер вам надо передать им это имя.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64140/discussion-on-answer-by-mikhail-vaysman------node-js-).